# jquery image animate rotation

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, rotation

I'm trying to use jQuery rotate to animate an image once it's containing anchor tag is clicked. The anchor tag has the class .show_hide. The code below is getting the correct element, but it isn't rotating.

http://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/wiki/Examples

```
$(function()
{       
    $('.show_hide').click(function()
    {           
        var $icon = $(".show_hide img");
        $icon.rotate({animateTo:180});

    });
});
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: are you sure, you are using https://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/source/browse/trunk/jQueryRotate.js ?

Comment: The above code works fine for me.

Comment: Do not post solutions within questions.  Please post your solution below and accept your own answer.

Comment: I tried but unfortunately I don't have enough rep to do so. Stack actually said edit the original post instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I figured out it was to do with the way I was including the plugin.

This wasn't working

```
$.getScript('jQueryRotateCompressed.2.1.js');
```

So I changed it

```
$.getScript('/js/jQueryRotateCompressed.2.1.js');
```